# Empty JTextField User Input Error

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextfield, break

I'm am trying to create a program that takes user input through a JTextField and converts it to an Integer for me to calculate with. I want to prevent breaking the program by typing nothing into the JTextField.
How can I detect when the JTextField is empty?
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good spot to use a regular expression. Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for basic information on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an if statement that checks something like this would work;

```
myJTextField.getText().length()>0
```

or

```
!myJTextField.getText().equals("")
```

Comment: `myJTextField.getText().length()>0` and change to `!"".equals(myJTextField.getText())` to avoid NPE !

Comment: the >0 Keeps dissappearing from my edits, I've re added it twice. Good point about NPE, however I wouldn't have though `getText()` ever returns NULL, only NPE would be a null textField in which case called `getText()` will cause the NPE

Answer (score 0):

you can make an easy if condition, if(jtextField.getText() != ""), maybe you also interested in regex, just google it! :)

Comment: a) you ***MUST*** use `.equals` for checking if a `String` is equal, == and != just check if they are the same instance.
b) Regex is slightly overkill for checking an empty string.

Comment: I don't meant use regex for checking if user has entered something in the textfield, but for checking number, ".", "," or something else relating to further implementation tasks.